# Sitecore Path Analyzer showing template names as paths

Tags: path-analyzer

I have rebuild the path analyzer and I can see the paths as templates. It is showing Internet & Home item correctly. After that, it is just showing template names. Even some base templates are visible as path nodes in the path analyzer reports.

The same reports showing correctly on QA environment, but this issue comes on production environment only.

Sitecore 8.2 Update-5

Any help would be highly appreciate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please double check if you have the "Group map data" selected. This would group nodes by template.